# Unable to import any androidx libraries due to incompatible aar issue

Tags: androidx, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

Trying to use `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha04` library and getting the below 'aar' error when trying to build my project.
I'm using gradle 6.7.

`Incompatible because this component declares a component, with the library elements 'aar' and the consumer needed a component`

```
plugins {
 kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.20"
 id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "0.2.0-build132"

}

group = "me.g"
version = "1.0"

repositories {
 jcenter()
 google()
 mavenCentral()
 maven { url = uri("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev") }
}

dependencies {
 implementation("android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1")
 testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit5"))
 testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0")
 testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.0")
 implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
 implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.0")
 implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.9.0")
 implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.0")
 implementation("com.github.docker-java:docker-java:3.2.7")
 implementation("com.github.docker-java:docker-java-transport-httpclient5:3.2.7")
 implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha04")

}

tasks.test {
 useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
 kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "15"
}

compose.desktop {
 application {
     mainClass = "MainKt"
     nativeDistributions {
         targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
         packageName = "cc-launcher"
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: This is an Android-specific implementation so you can't use it within desktop. If you have a look at its build.gradle file you can see its build for Android (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-compose-release/navigation/navigation-compose/build.gradle).

Comment: @2jan222 thanks for the response, any Idea how I can navigate through some views with compose desktop? I'm just having a simple sidebar with various items which I want to modify the main view when clicked

Comment: You could create a sealed class hierarchy of routes and update your UI with a state of the routes type. Then you could do a switch case as your router.

Comment: I personally copy the code from https://github.com/zsoltk/compose-router and delete the android specific stuff like the bundle.

Comment: @2jan222 how do I create a state object for a view? sorry new to compose and kotlin also.

Answer (score 1):

### Here is an example for a router:

```kotlin
@Suppress("MoveLambdaOutsideParentheses", "FunctionName")
@Composable
private fun Router(
    defaultRoute: ApplicationRoutes,
    content: @Composable (current: ApplicationRoutes, setRoute: (ApplicationRoutes) -> Unit) -> Unit
) {
    val route = remember { mutableStateOf(defaultRoute) }
    content(route.value, { route.value = it })
}
```

### You can define the structure of your routes as follows:

```kotlin
private sealed class ApplicationRoutes {
    object Menu : ApplicationRoutes()
    data class ViewWithData(val data: Any) : ApplicationRoutes()
    object Login : ApplicationRoutes()
}
```

With a data class, it is possible to pass values to the composable at this route.

### How to use it:

You call the composable router and pass a default routing, the route that will be displayed at launch and implement the content lambda.

The first parameter of the lambda provides you with the current route you can pass to a when to handle all defined routes.

The second parameter is a setter for the active route. When invoked the route will change.

```kotlin
fun main() = Window {
    MaterialTheme {
        val defaultRoute = Login as ApplicationRoutes
        Router(
            defaultRoute = defaultRoute
        ) { current, setRoute ->
            when (current) {
                Menu -> NavBtns(current, setRoute)
                is ViewWithData -> {
                    Column {
                        NavBtns(current, setRoute)
                        Text("NavigationFrom: ${current.data}")
                    }
                }
                Login -> NavBtns(current, setRoute)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The other composable for a complete example:

```kotlin
@Suppress("FunctionName")
@Composable
private fun NavBtns(current: ApplicationRoutes, setRoute: (ApplicationRoutes) -> Unit) {
    Column {
        Text(current.toString())
        Column {
            listOf(Menu, ViewWithData(current.toString()), Login)
                .forEach {
                    Button(onClick = { setRoute(it) }) {
                        Text(text = it.toString())
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm currently trying somethign a little simpler at the moment with mutableStateOf to defines the view to display based on a PageState enum. when I action this via an onClick() I get the usual error with onclick not allowed to use composable functions, unfortunately viewModel is not supported in compose desktop so what I wanted to do ie:change the state of pagestate is not working.

On your example how do I specify different views on the router class?

Comment: here's an example -> https://gist.github.com/glennmartinez/d2e56563a45ce9fa6b982bfbb6fc7f06 basic ui with two sidebar items with and onclick I want to change the view. telling me that onclick cannot take a composable.

Comment: The ``@Composable`` code will be translated to normal code via the Gradle plugin. Only code in a ``@Composable`` scope will be transformed, therefore you cannot use it in regular scoped code. You could compare that to a suspend function. If you think logically what would happen if you invoked a UI function inside an onClick. The framework would not know where to place and subsequently render the Composable.

Comment: Additionally, I would suggest that you check out the compose codelab about state. 
In compose you want to change data inside a state to change the look of the UI. You try to modify the UI directly from the onClick. Also, have a look at the mechanic of remember. Remember is used to keep a value from one composition to another. So for example if you create a state for a counter without a remember around it and you increment the counter state value the next time the composable gets composed the state will have its initial value again because the old mutableState was discarded.

Comment: Some Links: 
Why SealedClass ? because of exhaustive when statement: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html
Codelab about state:
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state